# Why am I being denied permission when I've given permission for both reading and writing

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I'm getting a `IOexception: permission denied error` when I try to create a file. I'm not quite sure how to use androids file systems so any good tutorials would be greatly appreciated as well.

I've defined the permission in the manifest (Read to internal storage, and write to internal storage) I took the slashes(/) out of my file paths. I can seem to find the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "Roomcsv");
if (!exportDir.mkdirs()) {
    try {
        exportDir.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("File Creation Error", e.toString());
    }
}

File file = new File(exportDir, "Users.csv");

if (!file.mkdirs()) {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("File Creation Error", e.toString());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a CSV file of a room database on external storage so I can pull it off the phone from a computer.

Comment: You need to request the permission with your code, see https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: This fixed my issue, Thank you.